# OPENUI5 ODATAv4 FunctionImport binding not working

Tags: function, binding, odata, sapui5

Currently, I have set up OPENUI5 to use a ODataV4 data source. This source includes a functionImport on a Collection without parameters.
In the XML View, I have defined

```
<Title text="{/Orders/OrderService.MyFancyFunction()}"/>
```

In the network trace I can see the function being called correctly:

Request:

```
GET Orders/OrderService.MyFancyFunction() HTTP/1.1
```

Response:

```
{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:50156/odata/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"Happy Hippo"}
```

However, the string is not shown on screen; inspecting the element through the UI5 inspector shows "text" being an empty string, but also having a correct binding to the function shown above.

Any ideas?

Thanks, regards

Jörg Fischer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug within the current implementation of ODataV4 in OPENUI5: it works well when the function is not using a namespace.